# Trying to get value from URL to then use in a method to find objects with that value

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mustache

I have URL http://localhost:3000/share/user=sampleuser which should display objects that have a author value matching that of the one in the URL. I'm getting an error when trying to call a function that takes the value from the URL then performing a find function in the database to find all entries matching the user.

```
    getSharedEntries(){
        const queryString = window.location.search;
        console.log(queryString);
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const author = urlParams.get('user');
        console.log(author);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.db.find({author: author}, function(err, docs){
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                    console.log('getEntriesForLoggedInUser promise rejected');
                }else{
                    resolve(docs);
                    console.log('getEntriesForLoggedInUser promise resolved, returned', docs);
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

```
exports.showSharePage = function(req, res){
    db.getSharedEntries().then((list) => {
        res.render('share', {
            'title': 'WEIR FITNESS PLANNER',
            'sharedActivities': list,
        });
        console.log('promise resolved');
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log('promise rejected', err);
    })}
```

```
router.get('/share/user=:user', controller.showSharePage);
```

```
<html>
<head>
    {{>header}}
</head>

<body>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{>sidebar}}
    <h2>Share Your Training Plan</h2>

    <input class="link" type="text" value="http://localhost:3000/share/user={{user}}" id="shareLink" readonly>
    <button class="linkButton" onclick="copyFunction()">Copy Link</button>

    <div>
        <table class="activityTable" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Week</th>
                <th>Activity</th>
                <th>Goal</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
            </tr>
            {{#sharedActivities}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{{author}}}</td>
                <td>{{{week}}}</td>
                <td>{{{name}}}</td>
                <td>{{{goal}}}</td>
                <td>{{completed}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/sharedActivities}}
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: `this.db.find` is this a client side JavaScript library?

Comment: I take it you are positive that const author = urlParams.get('user'); line of code works for sure.

Comment: Because the url you are using is just a little bit weird for me. Is it possible that your url should read http://localhost:3000/share?user=sampleuser

Comment: @drzsounds I've tried change the url to localhost:3000/share?user=sampleuser but now getting 404 Not found error. I need a way for a user to send another user a link which will display objects created by the first user

Comment: @T J it is a method defined in the model component  `find(){
        this.db.find({}, function(err, docs) {
            if(err){
                console.log('error');
            }else{
                console.log('documents retrieved:', docs);
            }
        })
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused with your question but, I assume that you have a problem in getting the value of `user=` in the URL.

The most easiest way to achieve this using Express Router is

```
router.get('/share', controller.showSharePage);
```

Now, you can request `get` as `http://localhost:3000/share?user=sampleuser`
You can access the `user` value by using `req.query.user` in the `controller.showSharePage` function

Request to accept if this helps...